# Tracking if a form is dirty in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm attempting to track the dirty (modified) status of a form in UWP that uses two way bindings between the view and the model.

My current method of tracking the respective changed events (TextChange for text boxes, SelectionChanged for combo boxes, etc.) works except for when the page is loaded with data.

What appears to be happening is that the bindings are still being evaluated after the page is fully loaded, thus making the form think it has been modified. From stepping through my code I'm building the following typical timeline when a page is loaded:

- Model is initialized (dirty = false)
- Data is retrieved and placed in the model
- Bindings trigger, filling the form (dirty = true)
- The Loaded event of the page is hit, at which point I set dirty = false
- Bindings continue to be set, thus resetting dirty to true
- (I need something here to set dirty back to false)

Is there an event that triggers after all bindings are evaluated for the first time, or some way of tracking whether the bindings have all been evaluated?

Edit: Some rough sample code to give a better idea of how I've got things set up

Model:

```
public class OrderModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
     private OrderCase order;
     public OrderCase Order
     {
        get
        {
            return order;
        }
        set
        {
            order = value;

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Order");
        }
     }
    private bool dirty;
    public bool Dirty
    {
        get
        {
            return dirty;
        }
        set
        {
            dirty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

View - Code Behind

```
    OrderModel Model;
    int OrderId;
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       //Call a method in the View Model which calls a WCF service
       //to get the OrderCase object out of our database and into the
       //Order object in the model
       Model = new OrderModel();
       Model.Order = await WcfService.GetOrder(OrderId);
       //Once this returns all the bindings start evaluating
    }
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       SetUndirty();
    }
    public override void TextBoxSetDirty(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //one of these exists for each type of control I use
        //this gets triggered when the text changes due to the model changing
        SetDirty();
    }
    public void SetDirty()
    {
        Model.Dirty = true;
    }
```

View - XAML

```
<TextBox 
 Text = "{x:Bind Path=Order.CustomerName, mode=TwoWay}"
 TextChanged="TextBoxSetDirty"/>
```

The view is a lot more of the same, including ComboBoxes, RadioButtons, ToggleSwitches, and a SyncFusion Datagrid

Edit 2:
I currently have a work around in place, another property called "UserHasInteracted" which is initially False, but upon either the page's KeyDown or Tapped events firing, it is set to true, and the SetDirty method is modified as such:

```
    public void SetDirty()
    {
        if (UserHasInteracted)
            Model.Dirty = true;
    }
```

The end result is that the form can't be set to Dirty until the user has performed some sort of interaction upon it.

This works about 75% of the time, and produces no false positives (saying the form is dirty when it isn't), but does produce some false negatives, because the Tapped event doesn't seem to fire when a RadioButton, CheckBox, or ToggleSwitch is clicked. It also fails if the only interaction the user performs is a single key press within a text box, as the TextChanged event fires before the KeyDown, however the chances that our users will only enter a single character into a text box as their modification is slim to none, so this one isn't a major concern.

Comment: can't you just set a IsDirty-Propertie in you other properties setters? The setter would only get called, when your data changed

Comment: The issue with that is that the actual data that is bound to the form and stored in the model is of a type that comes from a WCF data contract, so the setters of the properties in the object that comes from WCF can't access the IsDirty field of the model.

Comment: How would you know that the setting of bindings (the last bullet point) was completed? The answer to this question basically hinges on whatever event fires after the bindings have been set. Without an event, it would be a guessins game.

Comment: Could you add a method to for setting the private property instead of public property, hence not triggering the NotifyPropertyChangedEvent

Comment: @Flater my understanding is that the Loaded event is supposed to be the last event to fire before the user has control, but the control on_change events are still firing after the Loaded event, almost like a race condition.

Comment: @thezapper I'm not seeing what that would solve. I need the NotifyPropertyChangedEvent to fire in the model so the controls are filled with their data, but I need something to happen after everything is filled to set the Dirty field.

Comment: Can you show some code? As far as I'm aware, setting up bindings (i.e. making use of the `{Binding Path=MyProp}` feature) should not trigger onchange events. But in either case, seeing the code will help with answering this question.

Comment: Maybe you could bind the original data to the Tag of your controls as well and check if the data has changed in the triggered events. But maybe it would be easier if you show some code you already have...

Comment: I've edited the question to include an example of how I have it set up.

Answer (score 0):

How is your ViewModel instatiated?

For your class:

```
public class OrderModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
     private OrderCase order;
     public OrderCase Order
     {
        get
        {
            return order;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != order) { IsDirty = true; }
            order = value;

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Order");
        }
     }
    private bool dirty;
    public bool Dirty
    {
        get
        {
            return dirty;
        }
        set
        {
            dirty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work, or not?

```
OrderModel Model;
int OrderId;
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   //Call a method in the View Model which calls a WCF service
   //to get the OrderCase object out of our database and into the
   //Order object in the model
   var tempModel = new OrderModel();
   tempModel = await WcfService.GetOrder(OrderId);
   Model.Order = tempModel;
   //Setting the ViewModel's property only when getting order is completed
   //Once this returns all the bindings start evaluating
}
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   SetUndirty();
}
public override void TextBoxSetDirty(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //one of these exists for each type of control I use
    //this gets triggered when the text changes due to the model changing
    SetDirty();
}
public void SetDirty()
{
    Model.Dirty = true;
}
```

Otherwise you could try to add each single property in your ViewModel instead only one copy of OrderCase... just a thought

Comment: This would work if the entire Order object was being set, but the OrderCase type has a bunch of objects and properties within it, which are what's bound to the view.

It's the individual objects within the Order, like string CustomerName, that when changed needs to set the dirty property to true.

Comment: How do you set the Dirty property? Could you show us a more complete code? Thank you

Comment: This doesn't work for two reasons:

1. Despite the change to the OnNavigatedTo method, the race condition still occurs. Bindings are still being evaluated after the Page_Loaded method finishes.

2. Setting Dirty in the Order setter doesn't work because the Order object is only being set at the very beginning, the setter doesn't trigger when a property within OrderCase gets set.

Comment: If you aren't in control of OrderModel, you could maybe modify your ViewModel and expose every single property of OrderModel, so you have access to the setters of each properties... not the best solution, I know